# Latest Google Chrome version breaks CSS

Tags: css, google-chrome

After updating to the latest chrome version (87.0.4280.66 (Official Build) (64-bit)) an element with margin bottom no longer gets that margin when it is inside a parent with 100% height.

Could you please tell me if this can be reported to Google as a bug, or if what they do now is how it always should have been and so every other browser basically has a bug and Chrome is the only one who does it right?

HTML

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
test
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: red;
}

div {
  background-color: white;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 32px);
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}
```

JS Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/nez3aLqx/1/ (try it in latest chrome vs firefox)

Expected result (how it looks in previous version of chrome or any other browser that I have):
[image]

Actual result:
[image]

Comment: I've just updated it and can confirm the above. But than this is not a programming question at all, so should be closed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming problem.

Comment: How is it not a programming problem? It strictly depends on the programming definition of the css rules, whether it is a bug or expected result. Which is exactly what I am asking. Is google now treating those rules  programmatically correct or incorrect. @skobaljic

Comment: It is just a bug of new Chrome release, guess we can expect it to be fixed soon. Your code is quite correct, no issues in there. You can also [report it](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

Comment: Reported a bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1166189

Answer (score -4):

you can use `!important` in css to get priyority over others
like the code below, hope that can solve the issue,

```
div {
  background-color: white;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 32px);
  margin-bottom: 200px !important;
}
```

Comment: No. There is no clashing of CSS. I do not have two things settings margin-bottom on the same element. Here is the fiddle with important https://jsfiddle.net/eh1aqn37/ as you can see it made 0 difference.

Comment: I meant by putting ```!important``` in your code, your browser will never ignore that code